# HTTPS connection refused after redirect on my Nginx server

Tags: networking, iptables, ssl, nginx, letsencrypt

I’m unable to get to my web server via HTTPS. If I try and connect on port 80 the connection is redirected to port 443 as a quick wget shows:

```
--2021-01-04 22:45:51--  http://corballis.co.uk/
Resolving corballis.co.uk (corballis.co.uk)... 83.86.93.178
Connecting to corballis.co.uk (corballis.co.uk)|83.86.93.178|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://corballis.co.uk/ [following]
--2021-01-04 22:45:52--  https://corballis.co.uk/
Connecting to corballis.co.uk (corballis.co.uk)|83.86.93.178|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Resolving corballis.co.uk (corballis.co.uk)... 83.86.93.178
Connecting to corballis.co.uk (corballis.co.uk)|83.86.93.178|:443... failed: Connection refused.
```

I’m using Nginx and that seems to be okay

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;

server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    # gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css image/*;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-echo.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-subs-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-upstream-fair.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_upstream_fair_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;
text/mathml                           mml;
text/plain                            txt;
text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
text/x-component                      htc;

image/png                             png;
image/tiff                            tif tiff;
image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
image/x-icon                          ico;
image/x-jng                           jng;
image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
image/webp                            webp;

application/font-woff                 woff;
application/java-archive              jar war ear;
application/json                      json;
application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
application/msword                    doc;
application/pdf                       pdf;
application/postscript                ps eps ai;
application/rtf                       rtf;
application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
application/x-cocoa                   cco;
application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
application/x-makeself                run;
application/x-perl                    pl pm;
application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
application/x-sea                     sea;
application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
application/x-stuffit                 sit;
application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
application/zip                       zip;

application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
application/octet-stream              deb;
application/octet-stream              dmg;
application/octet-stream              iso img;
application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
audio/mpeg                            mp3;
audio/ogg                             ogg;
audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
video/mp2t                            ts;
video/mp4                             mp4;
video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
video/quicktime                       mov;
video/webm                            webm;
video/x-flv                           flv;
video/x-m4v                           m4v;
video/x-mng                           mng;
video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/corballis.co.uk:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

#    listen [::]:80;
#    listen [::]:443 ssl;

server_name corballis.co.uk www.corballis.co.uk;
root /var/www/corballis.co.uk/system/;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    
}

location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
}

client_max_body_size 50m;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sarahcorballis.com:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
#    listen [::]:80;
#    listen [::]:443 ssl;

server_name sarahcorballis.com www.sarahcorballis.com;
root /var/www/sarahcorballis.com/;

index index.html;

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
}

client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

I think my firewall rules are okay but here’s UFW status:

Status: active

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5900:5910/tcp              ALLOW       Anywhere                  
631/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
9191/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5900:5910/tcp (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
631/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
9191/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

And just to be sure, here’s the output of iptables-save:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Jan  4 22:55:28 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [111326:20063761]
:INPUT ACCEPT [12845:2431611]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [14360:1277629]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [14360:1277629]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan  4 22:55:28 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Jan  4 22:55:28 2021
*filter
:INPUT DROP [98:15256]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Nginx%20Full\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5900:5910 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9191 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan  4 22:55:28 2021
```

Finally, to be sure there's something listening in the correct ports, I ran lsof -l :80 and :443, which give:

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx    8578 www-data    6u  IPv4 327276      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    8580 www-data    6u  IPv4 327276      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    8582 www-data    6u  IPv4 327276      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    8583 www-data    6u  IPv4 327276      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   18370     root    6u  IPv4 327276      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

and (443):

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx    8578 www-data    8u  IPv4 327278      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx    8580 www-data    8u  IPv4 327278      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx    8582 www-data    8u  IPv4 327278      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx    8583 www-data    8u  IPv4 327278      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   18370     root    8u  IPv4 327278      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```

I have tried to run [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org) to set up new Let’s Encrypt  certificates but that fails, as I would expect, because it can’t get to the challenge directory via port 80 due to the redirect but for some reason (no doubt incompetence on my part) I’m completely unable to sort this mess out.

Any thoughts would be most gratefully received.

Comment: Could it be your gateway firewall/router? How about your ISP? Do they block port 443?

Comment: Check if it works on the local system, then inside the same network, then outside. Firewalls can be on multiple places. For example in common cloud setups there is an additional firewall by the cloud provider which might need to be configured.

Comment: I just [posted an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1615023/167207) that focuses on getting Certbot to handle the `acme-challenge` when a firewall is enabled. Hope that helps! But as @SteffenUllrich suggests, you should debug from the command line on the server itself. I would recommend doing header checks for `curl -ILk localhost` and even `curl -ILk corballis.co.uk`. That said, is the hostname actually `corballis.co.uk` because I am localist in Brooklyn, NY, USA and I cannot reach that server but I do see it [listed on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22corballis.co.uk%22).

Comment: PS: That said again, I did an `nmap corballis.co.uk` and see that ports 80 and 443 are open: `80/tcp filtered http` and `443/tcp  open https`

Comment: Thanks. I definitely own that domain and it's pointing to the correct IP address. Here is the output from curl -ILk localhost:
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2021 12:33:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 52
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Location: https://localhost/
Vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding

curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:443

Comment: And here is the output from curl -ILk corballis.co.uk (also done from the localhost server):

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://corballis.co.uk/
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2021 12:37:55 GMT
Server: lighttpd

curl: (7) Failed to connect to corballis.co.uk port 443: Connection refused

Comment: I also tried `ufw disable` and then run certbot again but it still fails with the same result codes etc.

Answer (score 0):

### You need to whitelist the Let’s Ecrypt `acme-challenge` request.

#### While Let’s Ecrypt is cool — because it is free — Certbot won’t work if it can’t get the `acme-challenge` request fulfilled.

I had a similar issue with an Ubuntu 16.04 server that I manage. I had setup Let’s Encrypt in the past and it worked well, but at some point the Let’s Encrypt decided to change the way that they confirm host identity to use an `acme-challenge` request.

The problem is they provide utterly no guidance — aka: useless help — in how to get around the [Catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22) of having an active firewall that might block/reject those requests. And the solution is so head-shakingly easy it’s stunning they don’t provide it as a matter of course.

You need to add the request for `/.well-known/acme-challenge` to the input chain on your firewall. In my case — where I am using IPTables directly — I had to change my input chain from this:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

To this:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m string --string "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge" --algo kmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Note the addition of this `acme-challenge` specific rule:

```
-A INPUT -m string --string "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge" --algo kmp -j ACCEPT
```

That is the magic that will allow the Certbot triggered process to be able to retrieve the `acme-challenge` request. The rule is fairly simple between the INPUT and ACCEPT action:

- `-m string --string "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge"`: Tells the firewall to detect GET requests for the `acme-challenge`.
- `--algo kmp`: Uses the `kmp` (aka: Knuth-Pratt-Morris) algorithm for string detection.

In your case I would adjust your `ufw-user-input` in the saved format it stores it in within `/lib/ufw/user.rules` (I believe) so the `ufw-user-input` chain looks like this:

```
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Nginx%20Full\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5900:5910 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9191 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -m string --string "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge" --algo kmp -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
```

I don’t have enough comfort or knowledge to know how to handle this from the command line of Ubuntu 18.04 using `ufw` but if someone out there can convert that line into a valid `ufw` command that would place it in the `ufw-user-input` chain, please feel free to share that in the comments.